Is there any options to push the protected info?

First, I don't know whether Git Kraken blocks it or Github blocks it.
If it's caused by Github, is there any way to push this file?
I am creating the website with OAuth2.0 in a group, so I need to upload this code.
And, I also wonder how the professional developers upload this kind of file.
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            clientId: ''
            clientSecret: ''
            redirectUri: "http://localhost/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: email, profile

I uploaded the file without these. I would like to get the answer.

If your real file contains the actual secrets, a more secure way would be to set them as secrets in GitHub Actions, and then inject them during the build. Or, depending on how you use them, they should be in a secrets manager (AWS Secrets Manager, Hashicorp Vault) and retrieved dynamically from the backend when required.

Github blocks it, and it is a setting for the repository to not allow pushes with secrets in them.
It can be disabled for the repository if you have permission to edit it.
https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-scanning/push-protection-for-repositories-and-organizations#enabling-secret-scanning-as-a-push-protection


Is there any options to push the protected info?

Rathenr than disabling that check on the repository level, you now have:

Reviewers can add a comment on push protection bypass requests for secret scanning (Dec. 2024)
Reviewers can now add comments to push protection bypass requests in secret scanning.
These comments help provide context, explaining the reasoning behind approving or denying a request.
Requesters gain clarity on why their request was denied, and other reviewers can better understand why a request was approved or denied.
The comment is included in the response email sent to the requester, as well as in the timeline of the resulting alert, the API, the audit log, and webhook responses.

Learn more about how to secure your repositories with secret scanning and push protection bypass controls.

By making a pull-request to main, with the right comment in the PR review thread, you can push your file to main.
